# Graph with too many points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I coded a python script to get a graph which dynamically change in a file. 
Here the code:

```
def get_plot():
  print self.data1 #initialized to [0,0,0,0]
  print '\n'
  plt.subplot(111)
  data0 = 0,1,2,3
  p1=plt.plot(data0,self.data1,'ro')
  plt.setp(p1, linewidth=0.5, color='r')
  .....
  plt.savefig("file.png")
```

I use a function to call repeteadly the function above. 
If I check the `self.data1` values, all works cause they change dynamically like I want. 
But, the graph which is saved contains 4 values for each value of `data0`, instead of just one.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you be clear?

I used:
self.timeout_source = glib.timeout_add(self.sleep_time,                 self.get_plot)

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be something you're not telling us.
I run the following:

```
plt.subplot(111)
data0 = 0,1,2,3
p1 = plt.plot(data0,[0,0,0,0],'ro')
plt.setp(p1, linewidth=0.5, color='r')
plt.show()
```

And get:

[image]

Comment: Oh sure, What I'd like to get. 
But I get what I said. 

I have the function above which is called in a interval set up by 

glib.timeout_add(self.sleep_time, self.get_plot)

Each time, the value oy "y" vector is different and it contains the last 3 previous values and a new one (It's a circular buffer)

Comment: @FrancoHh: You might try calling `plt.clf()` after your call to `plt.savefig()`.